# How to get a dynamically created user control to subscribe to an event?

Tags: events, variable-assignment, subscribe

I'm creating a tabbed code editor. There could be one to many editors open. When a new editor is created, I want to tell it to listen for various events from the main form such as FontChanged, FontSizeChanged, Cut, Copy, Paste, etc.

I don't want to hard-code the event handlers in the editor to the event on the main form. I want to assign the event to the editor. Something like:

usrControl.FontChangedEvent = mainForm.FontChangedEvent

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What language should this be coded in?

Comment: I'm using VB 2012. It's a WPF app. Thanks!